# Как сменить кодировку xml-файла с помощью хранимой процедуры SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь сделать процедуру с параметром(путь к файлу), добавляющую в таблицу данные из xml-файла. Нужно, чтобы процедура меняла кодировку файла(с UTF-8 на Windows-1251). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

(P.S. В файлах кириллица отображается некорректно, рандомные символы или знаки вопроса)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LoadXMLFile_manufactures]
    @path_file NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @XMLData XML;

    SET @SQL = '
        SELECT @XMLData = BulkColumn
        FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @path_file + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;'
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@XMLData XML OUTPUT', @XMLData OUTPUT

    MERGE INTO dbo.manufactures as target_mnftrs
    USING (
    SELECT
        DataXml.value('id[1]','INT') as id,
        DataXml.value('name[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') as name,
        DataXml.value('created_date[1]','DATETIME') as created_date,
        DataXml.value('last_update_date[1]','DATETIME') as last_update_date
    FROM @XMLData.nodes('/root/manufacturers/manufacturer') AS T(DataXml)
    ) as source_mnftrs
    ON target_mnftrs.id = source_mnftrs.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        target_mnftrs.name = source_mnftrs.name,
        target_mnftrs.created_date = source_mnftrs.created_date,
        target_mnftrs.last_update_date = source_mnftrs.last_update_date
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
        (id, name, created_date, last_update_date)
    VALUES 
        (source_mnftrs.id, source_mnftrs.name, source_mnftrs.created_date, source_mnftrs.last_update_date);
END
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что значит "меняла кодировку"? Нужно _открыть_ файл в правильной кодировке вместо дефолтной? Смотрите параметр [code_page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#bulk-input-file-format-options)

Comment: Alexander Petrov, просто данные в одной кодировке должны загружаться в другой
code_page использовал, но не сработало

Comment: Также непонятен "поменять кодировку". Судя по коду `SINGLE_BLOB` возвращает [varbinary] и затем передает напрямую в [xml]. Подозреваю, что выполняется преобразование "на лету" в формат [varchar] и только затем в [xml]. Попробуйте открыть файл через `SINGLE_NCLOB`, которая возвращает [nvarchar].